# MongoDB Export/Import Failed: error counting

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to export data from local database using:

```
mongodump --db ride4you --collection rides
```

But I receive the next error:

```
Failed: error counting ride4you.rides: not authorized on ride4you to execute command { count: "rides", query: {} }
```

What is this and what to do?
Plus, is there a way to export the whole database at once, instead by each table?

Comment: @Raz, Could you elaborate more , how you are doing mongodump?

Comment: Yes, I have ran mongod --auth and earlier I created a user with a password.

Now when I am trying to do any mongo comment, beside of use, like db.getUsers() or db.dropUser() I have receive an error due to not authorized.

Well, how do I authorize then?

Comment: @Raz, You can change authorization through db.changeUserPassword(username, password). You must ensure that you are using your correct database. I mean (use ride4you) through mongo command. And ride4you should be current database.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.changeUserPassword/

Comment: @Raz, if you Allows a user to authenticate to the database from within the shell through db.auth(). If you are getting authentication error through mongo shell then you can change the user password through db.changeUserPassword().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Raz, I have gone through your mongodump statement. You are doing mistake.

> mongodump --db ride4you --collection rides

As per your mongodump code , As i am able to understand in your mongodump code, there is `database name` (ride4you) and `collection name` (rides) without the path of dump (.JSON) file.

Let's start from beginning. As per MongoDB BOL , if you are in BIN directory . Just type along with `mongodump --help`. You shall get the `mongodump` command all details. Which i am copy and paste from my environment.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongodump --help
Usage:
  mongodump <options>

Export the content of a running server into .bson files.

Specify a database with -d and a collection with -c to only dump that database or

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/ for more informat

general options:
      /help                                                 print usage
      /version                                              print the tool
                                                            version and exit

verbosity options:
  /v, /verbose:<level>                                      more detailed log
                                                            output (include
                                                            multiple times for
                                                            more verbosity,
                                                            e.g. -vvvvv, or
                                                            specify a numeric
                                                            value, e.g.
                                                            --verbose=N)
      /quiet                                                hide all log output

connection options:
  /h, /host:<hostname>                                      mongodb host to
                                                            connect to
                                                            (setname/host1,host-

                                                            2 for replica sets)
      /port:<port>                                          server port (can
                                                            also use --host
                                                            hostname:port)

authentication options:
  /u, /username:<username>                                  username for
                                                            authentication
  /p, /password:<password>                                  password for
                                                            authentication
      /authenticationDatabase:<database-name>               database that holds
                                                            the user's
                                                            credentials
      /authenticationMechanism:<mechanism>                  authentication
                                                            mechanism to use

namespace options:
  /d, /db:<database-name>                                   database to use
  /c, /collection:<collection-name>                         collection to use

query options:
  /q, /query:                                               query filter, as a
                                                            JSON string, e.g.,
                                                            '{x:{$gt:1}}'
      /queryFile:                                           path to a file
                                                            containing a query
                                                            filter (JSON)
      /readPreference:<string>|<json>                       specify either a
                                                            preference name or
                                                            a preference json
                                                            object
      /forceTableScan                                       force a table scan

output options:
  /o, /out:<directory-path>                                 output directory,
                                                            or '-' for stdout
                                                            (defaults to 'dump')
      /gzip                                                 compress archive
                                                            our collection
                                                            output with Gzip
      /repair                                               try to recover
                                                            documents from
                                                            damaged data files
                                                            (not supported by
                                                            all storage engines)
      /oplog                                                use oplog for
                                                            taking a
                                                            point-in-time
                                                            snapshot
      /archive:<file-path>                                  dump as an archive
                                                            to the specified
                                                            path. If flag is
                                                            specified without a
                                                            value, archive is
                                                            written to stdout
      /dumpDbUsersAndRoles                                  dump user and role
                                                            definitions for the
                                                            specified database
      /excludeCollection:<collection-name>                  collection to
                                                            exclude from the
                                                            dump (may be
                                                            specified multiple
                                                            times to exclude
                                                            additional
                                                            collections)
      /excludeCollectionsWithPrefix:<collection-prefix>     exclude all
                                                            collections from
                                                            the dump that have
                                                            the given prefix
                                                            (may be specified
                                                            multiple times to
                                                            exclude additional
                                                            prefixes)
  /j, /numParallelCollections:                              number of
                                                            collections to dump
                                                            in parallel (4 by
                                                            default)
```

Mostly i am doing mongodump in my environment like

For a single database dump

```
mongodump -d myfirstdb -o C:\Test\TestDB.json
```

For all database dump at a time

```
mongodump --verbose C:\Test\
```

Here In first statement `myfirstdb` is database in my MongoDB Server. -o is for output directory options and `C:\Test`  is a folder where TestDB.json my dump (.JSON) File reside.

In second statement i have used `--verbose` . for more details output

**Note:** `mongodump` import all dump (.JSON) files in MongoDB Server at a time. But when doing `mongoimport` then it import one dump (.JSON) file at a time.

For Further your ref [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: not a full answer: he is attempting to dump a single collection not the entire DB as you do. Also to pass a name terminating with .json as you do in the "-o C:\Test\TestDB.json" part makes little sense since the name you provide will be used to create a folder under which mongodump will put the collections in separate bson/json files

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two errors here.

When you created user and enabled authentication `mongod --auth`, your first created user was NOT root/administrator (i.e. super user) who could do anything (like create new user with proper rights). Now you are stuck with user who don't have all rights.

Second, if your mongod is running at authentication mode, you need always authenticate when you use mongodump. So you need to give parameters -u (user name) and -p (password) so that database knows who is connecting and do that user have authorization to dump that database.

Comment: Probably first situation, how can be solved?

Comment: Start your mongod to maintenace mode, i.e. without --auth. Then start `mongo` and give commands `use admin
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "superuser",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [ "root" ]
    }
)` what create superuser. Restart your mongod again with --auth and use that user to dump `mongodump -u superuser -p 12345678 --db ride4you --collection rides --out dumpfile.dump`  OR use that superuser to create dump user with `backup` role. (of course, when you are creating that superuser, you can do that backup user same time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the collection was not existing in the database, once I created the collection the command went through fine.

So, basically the error "invalid namespace specified" means that the collection to export ".", in which "your_collection" comes as blank.

Comment: In my case the collection existed and I simply misspelled its name. So when "invalid namespace specified" is returned as an error one should first check both the "database name" and the "collection name". The namepace is indeed "<db_name>.<collection_name>"

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error output when trying to do mongo dump for a collection not existing in that database. Not sure why it is stated as "invalid namespace" instead of collections.

Also, I think the parameter should be '-d' instead of 'db'.

Comment: ,I think the parameter should be '-d' instead of **db**. YES. As already I have been mentioned in my answer.

Comment: the "usage" is not clear on this: on my installation (version 4.0.1 in windows): -d <dbname> --db <dbname> and /db:<dbname> are all accepted